# How to implement the OnResizeEnd Event for TFrame?

Tags: delphi, onresize, tframe

in the middle of the application is a frame. After resizing i need to rearrange controls on this panel (doing this in the resizing event is too busy).
Its more useful if this can be done once after all the resizing. But how?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to hook into message processing of the parent form (proof-of-concept code, tested with Delphi 2009, error and corner case handling need more work):

```
type
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
  strict private
    fOnEnterSizeMove: TNotifyEvent;
    fOnExitSizeMove: TNotifyEvent;
    fSavedWndProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure DoEnterSizeMove;
    procedure DoExitSizeMove;
    procedure ParentWindowProc(var AMessage: TMessage);
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWnd; override;
  published
    property OnEnterSizeMove: TNotifyEvent read fOnEnterSizeMove
      write fOnEnterSizeMove;
    property OnExitSizeMove: TNotifyEvent read fOnExitSizeMove
      write fOnExitSizeMove;
  end;

{ TFrame2 }

procedure TFrame2.CreateWnd;
var
  ParentForm: TCustomForm;
begin
  inherited;
  ParentForm := GetParentForm(Self);
  if ParentForm <> nil then begin
    fSavedWndProc := ParentForm.WindowProc;
    ParentForm.WindowProc := ParentWindowProc;
  end;
end;

procedure TFrame2.DestroyWnd;
var
  ParentForm: TCustomForm;
begin
  ParentForm := GetParentForm(Self);
  if ParentForm <> nil then
    ParentForm.WindowProc := fSavedWndProc;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TFrame2.DoEnterSizeMove;
begin
  if Assigned(fOnEnterSizeMove) then
    fOnEnterSizeMove(Self);
end;

procedure TFrame2.DoExitSizeMove;
begin
  if Assigned(fOnExitSizeMove) then
    fOnExitSizeMove(Self);
end;

procedure TFrame2.ParentWindowProc(var AMessage: TMessage);
begin
  fSavedWndProc(AMessage);
  if AMessage.Msg = WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE then
    DoEnterSizeMove;
  if AMessage.Msg = WM_EXITSIZEMOVE then
    DoExitSizeMove;
end;
```

Note that the messages are sent whenever a secondary message loop for moving / sizing has been started or left - there is no way to distinguish between moving and sizing. If you need to make sure that you catch sizing only, you should compare old and new size of the frame in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following Implementation.

-Hook owner form's on Resize event, handle it within your frame, and Fire any Event Handler the parent OnResize Might have had.

```
type
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FrameClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FOnResize: TNotifyEvent;

    procedure OnFrameResize(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    // custom Frame constructor
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TFrame2 }

constructor TFrame2.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  FOnResize := TForm(AOwner).OnResize;
  TForm(AOwner).OnResize := OnFrameResize;
end;

procedure TFrame2.OnFrameResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := 'resize fired';
  if @FOnResize <> nil then
    FOnResize(Parent);
end;
```

Comment: I think he wants to delay the resize "(doing this in the resizing event is too busy)". 
PS. The resize could also be done by placing a panel on the frame, with all the components in.

Comment: The OnResizeEnd event is right after the call of the Paren'ts OnResize. Just where it says `FOnResize(Parent)` you could insert there any code to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I think the it could be done by the resizing event stopping (to reset time) and starting a timer with et short timeout (lik 0,3 secs). Then the resize of the fram will be done shortly after the rest of the resizing.

Answer (score 0):

1) Mark your frame with special interface smth. like: INeedLayoutAfterResize :)

2) Write custom descendant of TForm that would capture resize events (as shown in earlier answers), than looks for its children and if some child marked, than re-layout its content.

actually I use such approach for save and restore controls state.
my custom from iterate over its children controls and look for Tag property if it is less then zero, write its state to ini-file.